# CompositionTarget.Rendering Lag

Tags: c#, wpf, input, rendering, user-input

I have an application that subscribes to the CompositionTarget.Rendering event as a kind of game "render loop". If I spend less than around ~20ms in the callback, things are fine and my app is responsive. Yet if I spend any time over this, the input events I subscribe to (MouseMove, MouseWheel etc) don't get called nearly as often, and so although my game still has a desent frame rate of 30fps or so, the input response becomes really laggy and unusable.

As mentioned, it renders at about 30fps, but the input events come through at about 5-10fps.

I assume it is to do with WPF trying to maintain ~60FPS (16ms)? and so it throttles the input dispatcher in the hope to regain some performance?

Is there any way to disable this "throttleing"?

Comment: [Setting lower framerate](https://www.wpftutorial.net/FrameRate.html) helps, but in my testing only by about 35% more input actions registered.

Answer (score 0):

The `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event can be fired several times for a single frame, you can extend it to fire only a single time for each frame. That can help for performance. Read more [here](https://evanl.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/efficient-optimal-per-frame-eventing-in-wpf/).

There is [an implementation here.](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/4fc36c67ea09d425496276112cd5358647be555d/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Shared/Controls/CompositionTargetEX.cs)

Answer (score -1):

**Wrong tools for the job**

You should ask yourself:

*Why am I developing a game using a platform that hasn't been designed explicitly for it?*

Comment: While I agree on this, I think the question is still a good one and its answer could teach us a lot about WPF.

Comment: Maybe the following reading will convince you that it's definitely a no-go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-render-on-a-per-frame-interval-using-compositiontarget

Comment: I appreciate it might not be the right tool for the job. It's acually more of an editor than a game. But still, your answer is not very helpful.

Comment: As I said to @CorentinPane, just read that link then maybe you'll acknowledge it's a bad approach.